# problem with realisation css grid for mobile

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following code.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-architecture-xgzef)

I have a footer part that has 3 items (copyRight, privacy, and terms).

For the desktop, I write for my footer following style

```
    .footer {
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 70% 15% 15%;
    }
```

And it is working well.

Now for mobile version (230px - 600px) I want to have following design.

[design for mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coth5.png)

Please help me to achieve that design using a grid. Maybe I should change the HTML div structure?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: @Rob, I put code part and image, I don;t put any other link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add class names to the divs you need to manipulate.
And add this css in the media query for mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 230px) {
  .footer {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .copyright {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }

  .privacy {
    grid-column-start: 1;
  }

  .terms {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
}
```

You can check this link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-engelbart-31jb9?file=/mystyle.css)

Also very helpful link for css grid in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)